# Tricky statistics select

Tags: sql, sql-server

Trying to figure out this for a while, but no luck. I have the following tables (MS-SQL 2008):
**students**
studentID – email – profileID

**courses**
courseID – name

**studentsCourses**
studentID – courseID

**profiles**
profileID – name

**profilesMandatoryCourses**
profileID - courseID

**studentsCoursesLogs**
logID - studentID –courseID – accessDate

Each student, when enrolls, is assigned a profile. For each profile there are a number of mandatory course. Those mandatory courses together with any other courses a user takes are saved in the studentsCourses table.

Whenever a student accesses a course the information is logged in the studentsCoursesLogs.

I am trying to figure out all the students that have taken all the mandatory courses based on their profile.

Any pointers appreciated.

Comment: "I am trying to figure out all the students..." So what have you tried?

Comment: And how do you decide that the student "have taken" (completed) the course. Does accessing a course at studentsCoursesLogs means that it is completed?

Comment: I tried many things but nothing that gets me what I need. I think conceptually I can't come up with the sql statement. I don't need the whole sql just some pointers.  Thanks

Comment: @wooer Yes, when a course it's being accessed. A student can access the same course multiple times and as a result there can be multiple studentID-courseID rows with different time stamps. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this should do it (assuming I've understood your data model and requirements correctly - and that in throwing this sample SQL together I've not made any mistakes - I didn't create your data model in a database). I'm pretty sure it should be close enough though.

```
select studentRecords.StudentId, 
       sum(case TakenCourseID when null then 0 else 1 end) as CompleteMandatoryCourses,
       sum(case TakenCourseID when null then 1 else 0 end) as IncompleteMandatoryCourses
  from (
          select mandatoryCourses.StudentID, mandatoryCourses.CourseId as MandatoryCourseID, takenCourses.CourseID as TakenCourseID
            from ( -- Courses student should have taken - based on their profile
                   select p.[Profile], pmc.CourseID, s.StudentID 
                     from profiles p 
                     inner join profilesMandatoryCourses pmc on p.ProfileID = pmc.Profile
                     inner join students s on p.StudentID = s.StudentID
                 ) mandatoryCourses
            left join
                 (
                   -- Course students have taken
                   select s.StudentID, s.ProfileID, sc.CourseID
                     from students s
                     inner join studentsCourseLogs scl on s.StudentID = scl.StudentID
                 ) takenCourses on mandatoryCourses.ProfileId = takenCourses.ProfileID
                               and mandatoryCourses.CourseID = takenCourses.CourseID
       ) studentRecords
group by mandatoryCourse.StudentId
having sum(case TakenCourseID when null then 1 else 0 end) = 0
```

It will give a recordset like the following....

```
 +----------------+-----------------------------+-------------------------------+
 |  StudentID     |  CompleteMandatoryCourses   |  IncompleteMandatoryCourses   |
 +----------------+-----------------------------+-------------------------------+
 |      1         |      15                     |        3                      |
 |      2         |       8                     |        0                      |
 +----------------+-----------------------------+-------------------------------+
```

If you just want a list of students who have taken all mandatory courses, you could wrap all of the above as shown here...

```
select studentID 
  from ( /* insert very long sql here */ ) 
 where IncompleteMandatoryCourses = 0`
```

Comment: I will mark it as accepted as it puts me on the right track.  <br> Thank you for the quick response